# sort order by desc not working as expected

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, sql-order-by

I have this query in SQL

```
SELECT Book FROM Library ORDER BY Book desc
```

My desired sort

```
[Expired]Web Publishing Co., Ltd.
[Expired]sBox Co.,Ltd
[Expired]mTertainment
wwww
```

but result showed as follows

```
wwww
[Expired]sBox Co.,Ltd
[Expired]mTertainment
[Expired]Web Publishing Co., Ltd.
```

Comment: You seem to be ordering by the table name...

Comment: sorry I typed wrong "SELECT Book FROM Library ORDER BY Book desc"

Comment: Your observed output is inconsistent with the query.

Comment: query is giving correct output, it sorts the string based on ascii value of character. you can check ascii value of each character here http://www.asciitable.com/

Answer (score 7):

I see two issues here with your ordering.  First is that the bracket symbol is lexigraphically less than alphanumeric characters, which is not in agreement with what you want.  Second is that you have a case sensitivity issue with your book titles.  This is resulting in `sBox` appearing *greater* lexigraphically than `Web`, even though the former letter appears earlier in the alphabet from a case insensitive point of view.

One way to get the ordering you want is to use two conditions.  The first condition separates book titles beginning with alphanumeric titles from those beginning with symbols like brackets.  The second condition uses a case insensitive ordering by the actual book title.

```
SELECT Book
FROM Library
ORDER BY CASE WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(SUBSTR(Book, 1, 1), '[^A-Za-z0-9]') THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
         LOWER(Book) DESC
```

Actually, perhaps a more exact way to handle this would be to check if the book title begins with any bracketed label, i.e. `^[.*]`:

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(Book, '^[[].*[]]') THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
         LOWER(Book) DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you need select the "[Expired]"? If not, maybe the solution is to replace it:

```
SELECT REPLACE('[Expired]sBox Co.,Ltd', '[Expired]', '') as book 
FROM dual UNION
SELECT REPLACE('[Expired]mTertainmentas', '[Expired]', '') as book 
FROM dual UNION
SELECT 'www' as book FROM dual
ORDER BY book DESC
```

Or like @Tim did show, with REGEX:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('[xxxa]sBox Co.,Ltd', '^[[].*[]]', '') as book 
FROM dual UNION 
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('[xxxb]mTertainment', '^[[].*[]]', '') as book 
FROM dual UNION 
SELECT 'www' as book FROM dual 
ORDER BY book DESC
```